How can I make visNetwork (in R) have curved edges but no re-layout when nodes intersect?
How can I make a visNetwork graph that has curved edges but so the nodes are allowed to overlap? The whole point of moving them around in my case is to get a better view of the connections, but when they "bump" it moves all of the nodes and obscures the graph.
I have physics turned off but it still happens. What can be done? I can use igraph layouts but they don't have the curved edges that I want.
library(visNetwork) # v2.1.2

nodes = data.frame(id = letters[1:6], 
                   label = letters[1:6])

edges = data.frame(from = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "d", "d", "e"),
                   to = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "e", "f", "f"))

visNetwork(
  nodes = nodes, 
  edges = edges, 
  physics = F
) %>%
  visEdges(
    physics = F
  )


Here is an example of curve edge:
library(visNetwork) # v2.1.2

nodes = data.frame(id = letters[1:6], 
                   label = letters[1:6])

edges = data.frame(from = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "d", "d", "e"),
                   to = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "e", "f", "f"))

edges <- (edges 
          %>% mutate(
            smooth.enabled= TRUE,
            smooth.type='dicrete',
            roundness=0.8
          )
)

visNetwork(
  nodes = nodes, 
  edges = edges
) 

Try other options explained here :

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/edgeStyles/smooth.html

And convert it to R visNetwork. For example "smooth": { "type": "cubicBezier"    } becomes smooth.type='cubicBezier'.
